# Blender Animation: Animated Influence over the period of time of a repeated action strip

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I have an action strip (frame 00...10), which is repeated 40 times via its playback settings (resulting in a 00...400 "big" strip).
I want to animate the influence of the resulting strip (0...400) in a whole.

How can I do this.

Comment: Is *Animated Influence* option not working for you? It is just below *Playback settings*

Comment: No: It settings are only have impact to each repeatition. The influence settings are repeated as well. I want one influence settings for the sum of all repeatitions as a whole.

Comment: There is also a way of multiplying zero action on existing strip. You are creating another action with zero keyframes on every animated parameter and than push it down as NLA strip, but with *Multiply* mode instead of *Replace*. Then stretch it to match general strip and animate influence of it